# How to share Ubuntu desktop screen to a smart TV?

Tags: 16.04, screen, multimedia, mediaserver, smart-tv

Is there any software I can install in Ubuntu desktop 16.04 to enable sharing screen to a smart TV just like in Windows? How to install and configure it?

Comment: There is Aethercast, which works with WiDi and Miracast, but it's in development and only works on a few Ubuntu Touch devices. http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-devs-working-on-aethercast-for-meizu-mx-pro-5-ubuntu-edition-501176.shtml

Comment: @Zacharee1 Is there anything stable? Does it works for Samsung and LG Smart TVs?

Comment: Old post, but I'm pretty sure the OP's question is unanswered. I was also looking for a way to cast video/audio to my smart TV over LAN or Bluetooth. I just read this though... http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/mkchromecast-cast-video-from-ubuntu
It's CLI only at the moment, but I believe it satisfies the OP's original question...thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I've used HDMI and VGA connections to share my screen.  I usually extend rather than share.  This only works if your computer is close enough.  Relatively long cables are available.

Comment: I was thinking about a software solution to share my notebook screen in a Smart TV

Comment: @ThiagoRiderAugusto Unfortunately Smart TVs tend to use proprietary protocols.  I've yet to sucessfully share to my Samsung TV from Windows, even though it is supposedly supported. Windows has paired

Answer (score 0):

To share I use Chromecast plus Chrome Plugin. To split only with HDMI/VGA cable.