# How to display/extend/mirror/cast Ubuntu 16.04 screen to a Samsung Smart TV that is connected to the same network?

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, display, samsung

How can I share/display what I am seeing on my Ubuntu system to a networked Samsung Smart TV? The Ubuntu system and Samsung Smart TV are LAN connected to the same network. The Ubuntu system is a workstation.

I found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796112/how-to-share-ubuntu-desktop-screen-to-a-smart-tv) however the solution there on using hdmi and vga cable isn't what i am looking for. I am looking for a solution akin to what we can get from mirroring or chromecasting.

Update:
I found the following useful links on this subject (but there is no mention of Linux/Ubuntu):

1. [Best Miracast and Screen-Mirroring Devices 2018](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/best-miracast-screen-mirroring,review-2286.html)
2. [How to Mirror
       PC to TV](https://airmore.com/mirror-pc-to-tv.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Samsung TV "Mirror Screen"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017249/samsung-tv-mirror-screen)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The answer in the link that you had provided uses "Google Cast". However this extension no longer exist in the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Your question is nominated to be a duplicate of that question. As that question is older than yours if found to be similar enough your question should be closed. As far as the answers to either question goes they do not get nominated to be closed as duplicates. Answers to your question here can be ported to the duplicate nominee if your question is closed as a duplicate. New answers can be added to the duplicate nominee as well if and when better solutions come out.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking about a non traditional solution...

Have you thought about setting it up as a two monitors network?

If you see your tv screen from your workstation may be you can find this link as a solution for configuring a two monitors set up...

Here is the right way to do it...

[Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html)

And a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816750/how-to-configure-two-monitors-on-ubuntu-16-04) to a similar question...

This is a way to connect your pc to the Ethernet.

It seems that your TV can already communicate to the internet, which will normally be through an Ethernet connection from your TV to your home Router (Wired or Wireless connection). Your PC can connect to the internet via the same Router. Normally the Router will allow free communication between any devices within the home, whether Wired or Wireless (it is an "Ethernet Bridge").

There is a table maintained within the Router which identifies the IP address and Ethernet MAC address of every device currently active on the internet; it is normally called a "Forwarding DataBase" (FDB). Look up the router's documentation, login and read this table to find the IP address of the TV and the PC. You should be able to use the "ping" command on the PC to check that you can reach the TV via the router.

By "streaming from the PC", I assume that you want to (legally) download video to your PC (eg overnight), and then play it on the TV without any interruptions? To achieve this, you need video server software on your PC, which is a compatible format to your TV, and the downloaded video must also be a compatible format.

You should be able to provide your TV with the IP address of your PC, and the port number of the video server on your PC. It should start delivering video to your TV, over wired or wireless Ethernet.

Hope it helps...

Comment: This approach will require connecting a hdmi cable from the computer to the Smart TV, if I am correct. My question had mentioned that I am not looking for such a solution; such wired technology isn't suitable.

Comment: If you have connected your tv on an Ethernet network your pc will detect it and then you can choose it as a secondary or primary monitor, but I can be wrong...

Comment: I will edit my answer with more information, hope it helps...

Comment: Although you can check this Open Flixr Media Server... may be is a solution too..

Comment: I can ping the SmartTV IP address. However, on Ubuntu 16.04, there is no `Activities` on Ubuntu 16.04 (available in Ubuntu 18.04). But in `Ubuntu 16.04-->System Settings-->Displays`, only one display is detected. Can you provide more details on setting up?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but try network, may be is there. See this link and follow the steps but adding your smarttv to another port... https://askubuntu.com/questions/844018/ethernet-port-and-wifi-adapter-not-detected-ubuntu-16-04